# Arraylist not working with android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I got a problem and I can't find it anywhere.
So I'am making this quiz app. And I got my mainactivity here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<Vragen> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    Vragen currentQ;
    TextView txtVragen;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butVolgende;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllVragen();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtVragen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVraag);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord1);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord2);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord3);
        butVolgende=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVolgende);
        setVragenView();
        butVolgende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grpAntwoord);
                RadioButton antwoord=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANTWOORD()+" "+antwoord.getText());
                if(currentQ.getANTWOORD().equals(antwoord.getText()))
                {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                }
                if(qid<5){                  
                    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                    setVragenView();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void setVragenView()
    {
        txtVragen.setText(currentQ.getVRAAG());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPT1());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPT2());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPT3());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

Here is my DBHelper and the questions are in there:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_VRAAG = "vraag";
    private static final String KEY_ANTWOORD = "antwoord"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPT1= "opt1"; //option 1
    private static final String KEY_OPT2= "opt2"; //option 2
    private static final String KEY_OPT3= "opt3"; //option 3
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_VRAAG
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANTWOORD+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPT1 +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPT2 +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPT3+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addVragen();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addVragen()
    {
        Vragen q1=new Vragen("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "CISCO");
        this.addVraag(q1);
        Vragen q2=new Vragen("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "BIOS");
        this.addVraag(q2);
        Vragen q3=new Vragen("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","Register");
        this.addVraag(q3);
        Vragen q4=new Vragen("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?", "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","Router");
        this.addVraag(q4);
        Vragen q5=new Vragen("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","BASIC");
        this.addVraag(q5);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addVraag(Vragen quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_VRAAG, quest.getVRAAG()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANTWOORD, quest.getANTWOORD());
        values.put(KEY_OPT1, quest.getOPT1());
        values.put(KEY_OPT2, quest.getOPT2());
        values.put(KEY_OPT3, quest.getOPT3());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Vragen> getAllVragen() {
        List<Vragen> quesList = new ArrayList<Vragen>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Vragen quest = new Vragen();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setVRAAG(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANTWOORD(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPT1(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPT2(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPT3(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

And here is my Logcat:

```
08-28 14:33:58.440: W/dalvikvm(21832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416e32a0)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4262)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17421)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-28 14:33:58.460: E/AndroidRuntime(21832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody please help me I'm stuck and need to get this finished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can You Please print the logs checking the size before accessing the list and while returning the list from your getAllVragen method. As you r accessing index 1(means second element) but size is 1 so you should access index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

Means that you tried to get the second element in an ArrayList that had only one element. So that means that when you do

```
quesList=db.getAllVragen();
```

You only get one result

Comment: I can't immedeatly see what's wrong in how the questions are stored and retrieved. What do you get if you call `rowcount()`?

Answer (score 0):

TABLE_QUEST table you have only single record 
  your qid is more then the size of your quesList

Check the quesList.size() compare to qid 
may be qid = 2  array size is 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Can You Please print the logs checking the size, before accessing the
>   list and while returning the list from your getAllVragen method. As
>   you are accessing index 1(means second element) but size is 1 so you
>   should access index 0 .

For ex : `Here is my program`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

public static void main(String args[]){

List abc = new ArrayList();
abc.add("Meena");

    System.out.println("list element is : "+abc.get(1));
}

}
```

**In above program my list size is 1 and accessing index 1(i.e 2 element). As a result i got following exception same as yours:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size:
1
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

So in short,

> ***nth element in list is represented by index n-1***